# Maximo: Add 'Create New Work Order' button to title bar?

Tags: user-interface, button, titlebar, maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1:

When a user is in an application other than WO Tracking, it takes three clicks (and a mouseover) to create a new work order (via the menu).

I would like to make it easier for users to create work orders.

Idea:

Is it possible to add a `Create New Work Order` button in the title bar -- so that the button is always present and requires only a single click?

[image]

---

For bonus points, what is the proper name for the "title bar" in Maximo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I would not denature the basic Maximo UI for such a request. The Quick Insert portlet exists for this reason. Basically, add a work order Quick Insert portlet to the users' Start Center.

They would now have to hit the home button and click on the Quick Insert link.

Start Center portlets information:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mbs.doc/startcntr/c_start_center_portlets.html

If you really want to add a button, you'll need to modify a specific `jsp` as stated above by Preacher.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `system.welcomemessage` MaxMessage (DB Config > Messages) to include the link behind a create new work order from the start center portlet. Sorry, I don't have time to flesh this out and test it, but this should steer you in the right direction. If it doesn't work, you'll have to edit `titlebar.jsp` under `maximo/applications/maximo/maximouiweb/webclient` somewhere.